# Valor “menor que” seja removido no R

Tags: r

Tenho um df que contém tempos negativos, por exemplo:

-1:-14:-56

Gostaria de pegar todos os tempos que fossem menor que 00:00:00 e colocasse 00:00:00 no lugar.

Estou fazendo atualmente um trabalho bem braçal na substituição desses objetos:

```
df041[,1:61][df041[,1:61]=="-1:-38:-1"] <- "00:00:00"
df041[,1:61][df041[,1:61]=="-1:00:-33"] <- "00:00:00"
df041[,1:61][df041[,1:61]=="-8:-57:-54"] <- "00:00:00"
```

Alguém tem ideia de como fazer isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aqui vai uma solução com o pacte `lubridate`.
Começa por definir uma função, `negativo`, que só modifica os valores com o formato `"HH:MM:SS"` onde pelo menos um desses números seja negativo. Depois aplica essa função às colunas da dataframe.

```
library(lubridate)

negativo <- function(x, replace = "00:00:00"){
  y <- hms(x)
  h <- hour(y) < 0
  m <- minute(y) < 0
  s <- second(y) < 0
  x[h | m | s] <- replace
  x
}

negativo(c("-1:-38:-1", "-1:00:-33", "-8:-57:-54"))
#[1] "00:00:00" "00:00:00" "00:00:00"


df041[, 1:61] <- lapply(df041[, 1:61], negativo)
```

A função está testada, o `sapply` não está uma vez que não há dados de teste mas não creio que haja problemas.

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigada. :)